# Is there a IconMode for a listview in qml?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

can someone say me how to set up a icon mode for my listViewe in qml?
like this:
[image: icon mode]

I know that this mode is available in the c++ version of the listview (`setListMode`)but in qml?

Greetings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a default component for this in QML but you can easily do one yourself using the [Gridview](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-gridview.html) Component and creating the delegate yourself.

```
ListModel {
    id: modelIcons
    ListElement { iconSource: "icon1.jpg"; iconText: "Train1" }
    ListElement { iconSource: "icon2.jpg"; iconText: "Train2" }
    ListElement { iconSource: "icon3.jpg"; iconText: "Train3" }
    ListElement { iconSource: "icon4.jpg"; iconText: "Train4" }
    ListElement { iconSource: "icon5.jpg"; iconText: "Train5" }
    ListElement { iconSource: "icon6.jpg"; iconText: "Train6" }
    ListElement { iconSource: "icon7.jpg"; iconText: "Train7" }
}

Component {
    id: delegateListElement
    Item {
        width: 80
        height: width
        Column {
            Image {
                height: 50
                width: 50
                source: iconSource
            }
            Text {
                text: iconText
            }
        }
    }
}

GridView {
    anchors.fill: parent

    model: modelIcons
    delegate: delegateListElement
    focus: true
}
```